A trivial question about Combining Conditional Probabilities in multiple event case
The chain rule of probability of 3 events is: $P(x_0 \cap x_1 \cap x_2)=P(x_0)P(x_1|x_0)P(x_2|x_0,x_1)$
Now, for 3 events $x_0, x_1, x_2$ and we are given the probability of first 2 terms in the RHS i.e. $P(x_0)$ and $P(x_1|x_0)$. Moreover we are given $P(x_2|x_0)$ and $P(x_2|x_1)$. How do we calculate : $P(x_2|x_0,x_1)$ from this?
Is it as simple as $P(x_2|x_0,x_1)=P(x_2|x_0)P(x_2|x_1)$?
And can we generalize this to any number ($N$) of events i.e. $P(x_n|x_0,x_1,x_2..)$ = $P(x_n|x_0)P(x_n|x_1)P(x_n|x_2)...P(x_n|x_{n-1})$
Its been ages any I have forgotten much about conditional probability in multiple events case so any help will be appreciated.

You can't. Consider flipping two fair coins, and let $x_0$ be the event of getting heads on the first coin and $x_1$ the event of getting heads on the second. These are evidently independent events, so
$$P(x_0)=P(x_1|x_0)=\frac12.$$
Now consider constructing $x_2$ in two different ways. First, suppose $x_2$ is the event of getting heads on a third fair coin flip. Then
$$P(x_2|x_0)=P(x_2|x_1)=P(x_2|x_0,x_1)=\frac12.$$
Second, suppose $x_2$ is the event that the first two coin flips are equal. Then
$$P(x_2|x_0)=P(x_2|x_1)=\frac12,$$
but
$$P(x_2|x_0,x_1)=1.$$

Can't we use Bayes Theorem as follows:
$\begin{align}
P\left(x|yz\right)&=\frac{P\left(y|x\right)P\left(x\right)P\left(z|x\right)P\left(x\right)}{P\left(x\right)P\left(yz\right)}\ \end{align}$

can you please clarify? My setup is an unfair dice with 3 binary digits on each face, thus total 8 sides. The dice is unfair so each of the face has different probability of landing. Now, if we are given:  the probability of each digit's binary values, and the conditional probability of first 2 digits values (as described in Q), can we calculate the conditional probability of 3rd digit's value if given the value and probability of first 2 digits?

And the answer is no, as I have demonstrated. I have shown that you can get two different $P(x_2|x_0,x_1)$ with the same $P(x_0)$, $P(x_1|x_0)$, $P(x_2|x_0)$, $P(x_2|x_1)$. Which means that there can be no formula which calculates the former from the latter.

I understand. And by extension the general case i.e. if conditional probability of $N-1$ or less number of variable groups are given (lets assume all such probability pairs are given), using that we can calculate the conditional probability of $N^{th}$ variable w.r.t. previous $N-1$ variables is also False. Am I correct?

That's correct.
